# Error channel for Spring Cloud Stream Service-Bus Binder

Tags: java, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure an error channel for [Spring Cloud Azure Service Bus Queue Stream Binder](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/tree/master/spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder/spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-queue-stream-binder) with no success. I've enabled the error channel via

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: produce
      bindings:
        produce-out-0:
          destination: service-bus-q-a
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

And tried defining a `@ServiceActivator`:

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "service-bus-q-a.errors")
public void errors(ErrorMessage receiveMsg) {
    System.err.println("receive error msg: " + receiveMsg);
}
```

I've also tried on `inputChannel = "errorChannel"` and `inputChannel = "service-bus-q-a.$Default.errors"`. Obviously I am missing something here but I couldn't find a working example.

EDIT: I'm using the following Supplier bean:

```java
@Bean
Supplier<String> produce() {
    return () -> {
        String msg = "a message to produce";
        LOG.info("Producing message: " + msg);
        return msg;
    };
}
```

According to the [binding naming conventions](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_functional_binding_names), the name of the binding will be `produce-out-0`. I can see that the message is indeed sent to `service-bus-q-a` (I have a consumer on the other side).

**EDIT AND SOLUTION:**

So it appears I had a problem with my environment, and after rebuilding it everything worked as expected and as [Garry Russell's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373403/503397). Sorry for the time wasted. 
For posterity, this is exactly what worked for me:

When declaring a binding

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        produce-out-0:
          destination: service-bus-q-a
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

The error channel that will be created will be named `{destination}.errors`, in this case `service-bus-q-a.errors`. In addition you have the global error channel `errorChannel` that will also be called if an error occurs. So you can use either

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "service-bus-q-a.errors")
public void errors(ErrorMessage receiveMsg) {
    System.err.println("receive error msg: " + receiveMsg);
}
```

To receive the errors from `service-bus-q-a` or

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
public void errors(ErrorMessage receiveMsg) {
    System.err.println("receive error msg: " + receiveMsg);
}
```

To receive the error from the global error channel.

Comment: It looks like they only recently added support for that: https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/commits/master/spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder/spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-queue-stream-binder. Oh - looks like that's only on the consumer side.

Comment: So there is no way to recover from producer send timeouts?

Comment: Sorry; I don't know; I am not familiar with that binder.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if there's a non-binder specific way to handle producer errors?

Comment: Hmmm - I just looked at their code and they do inject the `errorChannel` into the handler (https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/41b16bb5ba0dbdb37709bd9082bd5a58052664fa/spring-cloud-azure-stream-binder/spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-stream-binder-core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/stream/binder/ServiceBusMessageChannelBinder.java#L42-L54) so it should work if `error-channel-enabled` is `true`. Try using a debugger.

Comment: I've tried to put `error-channel-enabled: true` (look at my example), and it is still null, I can't find a way to initialize it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer` where the `isErrorChannelEnabled()` is tested. If it's false, then there is something wrong with your properties environment.

Comment: Exactly what I've done, but unfortunately I can't figure out what are the correct properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it with this yaml and the property is `true` as expected.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
    azure:
      servicebus:
        connectionString: Endpoint=sb://foo.bar
```

Are you sure your producer name (`produce-out-0`) is correct?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the supplier bean that I'm using, and I can see that the message is sent to `service-bus-q-a`. If you put an error channel `@ServiceActivator` does it gets called on producer send Timeouts?. Also, what `spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-queue-stream-binder` version are you using? I'm using `1.2.3`

Comment: I was using 1.2.3; but I don't have a real environment; I was using a dummy connection string, just to test the boolean is being set properly. `isErrorChannelEnabled()` is still true, and the error channel not null, for me when I changed my test to use your supplier bean with `produce-out-0` as the binding name. So it looks like your YAML is not being read if you are still seeing a `null` error channel in the debugger.

Comment: You were right, it was a problem with my env. I have updated my question with the complete solution and I'm marking your answer as correct. Thanks and sorry for the time wasted.